# Tkinter can't get values to the function on button click

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

So, I try to get the values from inputs (3) and pass them on to a function on a button click.

This is what I have now:

```
Label(self.master, text="Name").grid(row=0, sticky=W)
    Label(self.master, text="Username").grid(row=1, sticky=W)
    Label(self.master, text="Email").grid(row=2, sticky=W)

    self.e_name = Entry(self.master).grid(row=0, column=1)
    self.e_username = Entry(self.master).grid(row=1, column=1)
    self.e_email = Entry(self.master).grid(row=2, column=1)

    Button(self.master, text="Login", command=self.login_client).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=E)
```

And the function:

```
def login_client(self):
    print(self.e_name.get())
```

Now, I get this error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`...

The full code of the file can be found here: https://gist.github.com/RosiersRobin/343c0194fde2e8e3184f24cb5aecac28

I just want the input from the user to be given in the function `login_client`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the `.grid()` call. grid returns `None`, so `self.e_name` will be `None`. Just change these lines to these ones:

```
self.e_name = Entry(self.master)
self.e_name.grid(row=0, column=1)
self.e_username = Entry(self.master)
self.e_username.grid(row=1, column=1)
self.e_email = Entry(self.master)
self.e_email.grid(row=2, column=1)
```

Comment: Gash, I knew it was something stupid... Thank you, alot!

Comment: @Robin Can you accept the answer?